# Cannot update the column information in table parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a table lets call "Post" which has 3 columns `"UserA"<ParseUser>`, "`UserB"` and `"Status"<String>`.
Data consists of UserA currentUser, UserB another ParseUser, status => A
When I am going to update the status from "A" to "B" it throw me error

```
com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in as the user you're trying to modify. A possible solution would be to call a Cloud Code function and use the Master Key to do this.

The Cloud Code guide is here: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Answer (score 0):

You should add below code to let `afterSave` / `beforeSave` hooks know that you are updating table directly.

```
if (request.master) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
}
```